# showing a box type-view on click of a button and on click of a tab bar item

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

In my application, i need to show a dilog-type view when a user clicks on a `UIButton`. I need to do the same thing when the user clicks on a `tabBar` item of a `UITabBar`

Sorry, in order to make myself clear, i had to create it in paint. Should i create a view with background image of the dilog box, and add two buttons in the view accordingly? I also need to  give an alert-view like effect to the view when it is shown.

How do i implement it in a `tabBarController?`

[image]

On clicking on the red button, the view with black border should be shown with an alert-view type effect.

Comment: is it iPhone application or IPad!

Comment: You can do this in Ipad with UIPoviewController and in Iphone with UIActionSheet but then how you will change the tab if those buttons are presenting the Pop view

Comment: I have not worked on UIActionSheet or UIPopViewController yet. Do they cover the entire screen??

Comment: no, UIActionSheet will take half of screen and popover can take any frame you define

Comment: ok.. i will do some studying and then try it out.. Will get back to you with the results soon